# python regex - find one of several optional groupings of characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following (discrete) strings:

```
um
yum
umpire
µm
mi
micro
```

These strings would be find as-is, not as part of a longer text. (They are possible cell values in a spreadsheet).

I wish to find all strings that are either "um" or "µm" or "mi" or "micro"  (but not umpire or yum)

I am struggling with understanding testing for character groupings. Here is what I have:

```
[(um)(µm)(mi)]
```

I've also tried variations, such as:

```
^[(?:um)|(?:µm)|(?:mi)]
```

But haven't yet found the magic.

[RegEx 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTcAyg/1)

Desired outcome would be if the following (above, top) strings return True:

```
"um", "µm", "mi", "micro"
```

Comment: elaborate whether it should search through an arbitrary  text or strict word-per-line text?

Comment: `[...]` is called character class and there is no grouping of text inside a character class. Engine matched only one of the given character sets inside. Read more about it: https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with anchors:

```
^(?:[uµ]m|mi(?:cro)?)$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTcAyg/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:` Start non-capture group. This is a non-capture group because it performs the operations (i.e returns the boolean true/false), but doesn't select the specified text

  - `[uµ]m`: Match `u` or `µ` followed by `m`, i.e matching `um` and `µm`
  - `|`: OR
  - `mi(?:cro)?`: Match `mi`, or with `cro` on the end if you want.
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

We use the `^` and `$` (anchors) to ensure that there is a match [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the regex is the entirety of the string: that's why we have the `?:`, because its effects are contained within the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

are there any spaces around 'um ', ' um' , or ' um '? You could use that as a boundary.

```
import re

your_string = 'um yum umpire µm mi micro'

rx = re.compile(r'\s*(um|mi|µm)\s*')

s = rx.search(your_string)
```

Something like this? Need more specifics on your string